# Check if email address exists front end with AJAX in a plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery, ajax, email

I am pulling my hair out trying to figure this out. I have followed the wordpress codex here for AJAX: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

All I keep returning is 0, I never get a 1. Any idea why? My code is as follows.

PHP:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'live_validation' );
add_action('wp_ajax_validate_email', 'validate_email_input');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_validate_email', 'validate_email_input');

function live_validation() {
    wp_enqueue_script( "validate_email", STRIPE_BASE_URL . 'inc/js/check-email.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( "validate_email", "validateEmail", array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

function validate_email_input() {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if ( email_exists($email) ) {
        echo 1; 
    } else {
        echo 0;
    }
    exit;
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('input[name=email]').keyup(function() {

        var input_value = $(this).val();

        $.post( validateEmail.ajaxurl, { action:'validate_email', email:input_value }, function(data) {
            $('.message').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <label for="email"><?php _e('Email', 'oe'); ?></label>
    <input type="text" size="20" id="email" name="email" />
    <span class="message"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. It always helps to read the codex thoroughly!

> "ATTENTION: When you are writing a plugin (in plugin wp_ajax usage)
>   place lines below in your main plugin file, e.g. myplugin.php"

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29

Just make sure all of your AJAX requests go in your main plugin file.

Answer (score 2):

I'll guess that you're testing this by entering your admin email address. Have a look at the Codex page for [`email_exists()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/email_exists):

> If the E-mail exists, function returns the ID of the user to whom the E-mail is registered.

If you're entering the email address of the first user created for a site, the user ID will be `0`, so `if ( email_exists($email) )` for that user will evaluate false. The example given on that page does not account for this situation.

Comment: I wish that was the case :/ I am entering a "test" user's email I created.

Comment: well your code otherwise works for me.

Comment: Weird. Any idea what else could be causing an issue?

Comment: not sure. I would start by just echoing back the email address to make sure the function is getting called, the 0 could be an error before the email_exists check happens, or it could be the 0 you're echoing yourself.

Comment: I don't believe the function is getting called I tried just echoing the address with no luck. Trying to figure out how to debug this.

Comment: what file is your php code in?

Comment: Appreciate your help, lead me to read the codex more and find the problem. Thanks!

Comment: aha, glad you solved it!

Comment: If you want to change the answer to reflect how it was solved I will gladly accept it. I wouldn't have found it out without you asking where my file was located.

Comment: you can accept your own answer, as that was the solution that fixed it for you.